# How could i trigger click event for all <a> elements sequentially using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I have a webpage that contains many  links. I want to trigger click event for all of them automatically and sequentially(one by one).I do not know how to make this happen with puppeteer.Could anybody give me some advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
const selector = 'a.someclass';
const elements = await page.$$(selector);
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const element = elements[i];
  await element.click();
}
```

Comment: Actually, when i trigger ```element.click()```, it will cause browser to open a new page.As i read from [linkg](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options)here, i should use ```page.waitForNavigation()```.My question is should i use ```page.waitForNavigation()``` every time when i trigger ```element.click()```(in the above for loop) and if so, what the code should look like?As i see, when a new page is opened, puppeteer will give a warning: **element is detached from document**.What does this mean? What is behind when i open a new page？

Comment: I think you need to add more information about the particular problem you are trying to solve. Why do you have to click these links? What are the links going to, other pages, a file you want to download?